# How to read xsi:type with java annotations

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-namespaces

I want to read in a xml-file based on jaxb to my objectoriented structure.

Lets say this is my xml-file:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <children xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <child xsi:type="girl">
            <age>12</age>
            <isdancing>true</isdancing>
        </child>
        <child xsi:type="boy">
            <age>10</age>
            <issoccerplayer>true</issoccerplayer>
        </child>
    </children>
```

*children* is some kind of wrapper element including multiple *child* elements. A *child* can either be a boy or a girl specified by xsi:type. These two classes have some elements in common (like *age*) and some different (excluding) elements (like *isdancing* or *issoccerplayer*)

To read the file, i have this method:

```java
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws JAXBException
    {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext;
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Children.class);             
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        File file = new File("C:/test.xml");
        if (!file.exists()) System.out.println("File does not exist");

        Children children = (Children) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        System.out.println(children.toString());
    }
```

My Children class looks like this:

```java
    @XmlRootElement(name="children")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Children {

        @XmlElement(name="child")
        private List<Child> childrenList;

        public List<Child> getChildren() { return childrenList; }
        public void setChildren(List<Child> children) {this.childrenList = children;}

    @Override
        public String toString() {
            return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this);
        }
    }
```

My Child class looks like this:

```java
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Child {

    @XmlAttribute(name="xsi:type")
    private XsiType xsiType;

    private int age;

    @XmlElement(name = "isdancing")
    private boolean isDancing;

    @XmlElement(name = "issoccerplayer")
    private boolean isSoccerPlayer;

        //Getter and setter for all fields

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this);
        }
    }
```

And my XsiType class looks like this:

```java
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class XsiType {

        @XmlAttribute(name="xsi:type")
        private String name;

        @XmlValue
        private String value;

        public String getName() { return name; }
        public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
        public String getValue() { return value; 
        public void setValue(String value) { this.value = value; }
    }
```

In my pom.xml i have included the following dependencies:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

My problem is now, that the output is ok, but the element xsiType of Child-class is always null or otherwise  it ends up in IllegalAnnotationExceptions, which are related to XmlTest.model.Child.xsiType

So i expect there is a mistake by setting any kind of @Xml-Annotation. Can somebody help me by finding the mistake?

The target is to iterate of the list of children and decide at runtime (based on the xsiType), if this is a girl or a boy.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need your `XsiType` class.
You can just use `String` instead.

In your `Child` class 
the `xsiType` attribute should look like this.

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "type", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
private String xsiType;
```

Notice: in the `@XmlAttribute` annotation

- use `name = "type"` (without the prefix `xsi:`)
- specify the [`namespace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAttribute.html#namespace()) parameter as given in your XML
  by `xmlns:xsi="..."`

---

By the way:
Instead of typing the string `"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`
you should better use the constant
[`XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_INSTANCE_NS_URI`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/XMLConstants.html#W3C_XML_SCHEMA_INSTANCE_NS_URI).
So your improved code would like this:

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "type", namespace = XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_INSTANCE_NS_URI)
private String xsiType;
```

Comment: Thanks man, i think i found my mistake. I always tried to put "xsi" into *namespace*. XMLConstants would be nicer, but i will receive Xml-files from another external source, that i can not manipulate.

Comment: Another question, maybe you can help again: Instead of using the approach above, is it possible to create two classes "Boy" and "Girl" (which maybe inheritate from an empty abstract "Child"-class) and have a *List<AbstractChild>*, which then holds *Boy* and *Girl*-Objects?

Comment: @Alex Yes, this is possible. Search for "JAXB unmarshal instances of subclasses into List".

Comment: Oh i am sorry, maybe i expressed myself a little bit ambiguous. I mean, i still have the "xsi:type"-attribute in *child*-elements. There is no distinction between <boy> and <girl> tags. Is there a possibility to instantiate directly Boy and Girl-objects and put them into a *List<AbstractChild>* based on the value of the *xsi:type* ?

Answer (score 1):

xsi type is usually used to express references to concrete types. Jaxb can use xsi types without further workarounds.

Create a `Boy` and a `Girl` class that extend `Children`. (You might need to adjust the type names with `@XmlType`). With that, all elements with `xsi:type=Girl` will be bound to the class `Girl`

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({ Boy.class, Girl.class }) // Either use @XmlSeeAlso to register classes in the JaxbContext
                                       //  or add them to the context directly
public class Child {

    private int age;

    @XmlElement(name = "isdancing")
    private boolean isDancing;

    @XmlElement(name = "issoccerplayer")
    private boolean isSoccerPlayer;

    // Getter and setter for all fields

}

@XmlType(name = "boy") // can be omitted if default value matches with the default value
public class Boy extends Child {

}

@XmlType(name = "girl")
public class Girl extends Child {

}
```

Complete selfcontained example:

```
package jaxb;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

public class Inheritance {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext;
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Children.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

        String x = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\r\n"
                + "    <children xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">\r\n"
                + "        <child xsi:type=\"girl\">\r\n" + "            <age>12</age>\r\n"
                + "            <isdancing>true</isdancing>\r\n" + "        </child>\r\n"
                + "        <child xsi:type=\"boy\">\r\n" + "            <age>10</age>\r\n"
                + "            <issoccerplayer>true</issoccerplayer>\r\n" + "        </child>\r\n" + "    </children>";

        Children children = (Children) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(x));
        System.out.println(children.getChildren().toString());
    }

    @XmlRootElement(name = "children")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public static class Children {

        @XmlElement(name = "child")
        private List<Child> childrenList;

        public List<Child> getChildren() {
            return childrenList;
        }

        public void setChildren(List<Child> children) {
            this.childrenList = children;
        }

    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlSeeAlso({ Boy.class, Girl.class })
    public static class Child {

        private int age;

        @XmlElement(name = "isdancing")
        private boolean isDancing;

        @XmlElement(name = "issoccerplayer")
        private boolean isSoccerPlayer;

        // Getter and setter for all fields

    }

    @XmlType(name = "boy")
    public static class Boy extends Child {

    }

    @XmlType(name = "girl")
    public static class Girl extends Child {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but it seems it does not work. It ends up in a InstantiationException. I still use "@XmlElement(name="child")
 private List<Child> child = new ArrayList<Child>();" Do i have to modifiy anything at this line?

Comment: Btw, are static classes allowed in Java? I think above classes are not nested.

Comment: Can you provide the complete error? I usually test code for stackoverflow in a single class hence the "static" keyword. I added my complete example.

Comment: @Alex Nice solution. This should be the accepted answer, rather than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Clean solution for second approach (based on separate class-files):

```java
public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException
    {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Children.class);             
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        File file = new File("C:/test2.xml");
        Children children = (Children) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

        for (Child c : children.getChildren()) {
            if (c instanceof Boy) {
                System.out.println(((Boy)c).toString());
            } else if (c instanceof Girl){
                System.out.println(((Girl)c).toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Children.java

```java
@XmlRootElement(name="children")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Children {

    @XmlElement(name="child")
    private List<Child> childrenList;

    public List<Child> getChildren() { return childrenList; }
    public void setChildren(List<Child> children) {this.childrenList = children;}

    @Override
    public String toString() { return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this); }
}
```

Boy.java

```java
@XmlType(name="boy")
public class Boy extends Child {

    @XmlElement(name = "issoccerplayer")
    private boolean isSoccerPlayer;

    public boolean isSoccerPlayer() { return isSoccerPlayer; }
    public void setSoccerPlayer(boolean isSoccerPlayer) { this.isSoccerPlayer = isSoccerPlayer; }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this); }
}
```

Girl.java

```java
@XmlType(name="girl")
public class Girl extends Child {

    @XmlElement(name = "isdancing")
    private boolean isDancing;

    public boolean isDancing() { return isDancing; }
    public void setDancing(boolean isDancing) { this.isDancing = isDancing; }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this); }
}
```

Child.java

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({ Boy.class, Girl.class }) 
public abstract class Child {

    private int age;

    public int getAge() { return age; }
    public void setAge(int age) { this.age = age; }
}
```

The output should be:

```
de.home.myproject.XmlTest.model.Girl@12edcd21[isDancing=true,age=12]
de.home.myproject.XmlTest.model.Boy@27bc2616[isSoccerPlayer=true,age=10]
```